# I want to get rid of decimals in my python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(plot1f['year'][0:5, ], plot1f['total_trips'][0:5, ], color = 'red', label = 'AK')
ax.plot(plot1f['year'][5:10, ], plot1f['total_trips'][5:10, ], '--', label = 'AL')
ax.plot(plot1f['year'][10:15, ], plot1f['total_trips'][10:15, ], '--k', label = 'AR')
ax.plot(plot1f['year'][15:20, ], plot1f['total_trips'][15:20, ], color = 'blue', label = 'AZ')
ax.plot(plot1f['year'][20:25, ], plot1f['total_trips'][20:25, ], '^--k', label = 'CA')
ax.legend()

ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Total trips per 1000')
ax.title.set_text('How flights to each state changed from 2004 to 2008')
plt.show()
```

The graph showed this:
[plot1f graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJWDC.png)

I want to get rid of the decimal places for the year.... I've tried ax[0][0].set_xticklabels(plot1f['year'].astype(int)), but I'm not too sure how to use it haha.. The data frame for year is all shown as 2004, 2005, 2006 etc so I don't know what went wrong.

Appreciate any help that comes my way, thank you!

** EDIT**

To be clearer, this is the data frame for `plot1f`:
[plot1f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aGow.png)

Types: [plot1f.dtypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ShMy.png)

Hope this helps you understand my problem better.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a definition for `plot1f` so I hazard a guess that the `f` suffix indicates floating point. If there's an equivalent without a suffix (eg, `plot1` ?) then that's probably what you want.

Comment: @JamesMcPherson heyy sorry i shouldve been clearer, plot1f is actually what I named my variable to be haha. I did tried to change to something else but it showed the same graph with those weird looking decimals :(

Comment: In that case, I'd specify your args as `int(plot1f['year'][0:5])` etc etc

Comment: @JamesMcPherson i did that and it return me this > TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>. plot1f was queried by me so im not sure if i was suppose to do what you  mentioned before i plotted.

Comment: Does the year column contain any NaNs?

Comment: @r-beginners none at all, its a repetitive of 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007 and 2008. The letters in plot1f represents US states and I took accumulated each year's flight to that particular state and placed it into a data frame which gave ```plot1f```.

Comment: You mention that plot1f is a dataframe - so iirc you should be able to use `plot1f["year"]` and `plot1f["total_trips"]` as bare numbers. By appending `[0:5,]` etc, you're turning that element into a series rather than leaving it as a number

Comment: @JamesMcPherson oh i had no idea that it would change it to a series... hmm because I want to plot a line plot that has the year below and the lines representing state.. seen from ```plot1f```, I don't think I am able to plot without indicating which rows I want T_T

Comment: @JamesMcPherson i attached the type in the post, maybe that might give you more info.. apparently its still int64

Comment: okay nvm ignore the above comment^ i get what you mean by it will turn the element to a series

Comment: I was able to confirm the event with your data and code. I can't give you a clear explanation, but I think it was automatically determined as a numerical value. So please add the following code as a countermeasure. `ax.set_xticks(range(2004, 2009, 1))`

Comment: @r-beginners DUDEEEE URE A LIFE SAVER!! IT WORKED T_T THANK YOU SO MUCH..